# Converting Wordpress Categories into Tags

Tags: wordpress

I imported about 60 posts from my old blogger blog into my new wordpress blog. The handy import process took the blogger "labels" and turned them into wordpress "categories".

Since I used the blogger labels as tags, I would like to find a simple way to turn the categories into tags without doing this task manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Administration Interface, then on the left click on **Tools** and then **Import**, then click on **Categories and Tags Converter**.